# Proper way of using Clockskew in OWIN JWT OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, owin

I have an application using following packages

```
Autofac version="4.8.1" targetFramework="net471"
Autofac.Owin version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471"
Autofac.WebApi2" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471"
Autofac.WebApi2.Owin" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net471"
jose-jwt" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.7" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.Owin" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net471"
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net471"
Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net471"
Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net471"
Serilog" version="2.7.1" targetFramework="net471"
Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net471"
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net471"
```

Server is issuing tokens with expiry time of 20 minutes.

In resource server I have following configuration

```
TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new 
TokenValidationParameters()
{
     ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_allowedClockDriftSeconds),
     IssuerSigningKey =   ...
     ValidateIssuer = true,
     ValidateAudience = true,
     RequireSignedTokens = true,
     ValidIssuer = "...",
     ValidAudience = "....",
 };

 app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
 {
      AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
      AllowedAudiences = new[] { "ConsumerDataServices" },
      IssuerSecurityTokenProviders =  new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
      {...},
      TokenHandler = new JoseJwtTokenHandler(decryptionHandler, logger),
      TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters,
  });
```

Auth Server is issuing tokens as JWE Tokens. JoseJwtTokenHandler is overriding ReadToken to decrypt and return JWT Token,

Everything works find for 20 minutes. I Can see my claims in principal.Identity in AuthorizationFilterAttribut. But after 20 minutes authorization stops working as principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated is set to false and claims are empty. On debugging I can see that JoseJwtTokenHandler is working fine.

In my logs I can see following

Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware Warning: 0 : expired bearer token received

Looking at code of Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler

```
DateTimeOffset currentUtc = this.Options.SystemClock.UtcNow;
if (ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.HasValue && ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value < currentUtc)
{
    this._logger.WriteWarning("expired bearer token received");
    return (AuthenticationTicket) null;
}
```

It looks like OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler is ignoring ClockSkew.

I have spent lot of time on it but couldn't get it to work. Does what I am doing looks OK? If not what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm not understanding something, but shouldn't the token stop working after 20 minutes if you're only assigning a token with a 20 minute lifetime? What value is `_allowedClockDriftSeconds` such that you're expecting the token to not expire?

Comment: This is to allow some margin for difference in auth server and resource server clocks. As these are two different machines and clocks can be out of sync. Clockskew will let token work even if there is some difference in both clocks. With clock skew token's practical vaid lifetime is issuetime-clockskew to expiry time+clockskew

Comment: It's set to 600 seconds for testing right now.

Comment: @Omair - I just encountered the same issue.  Did you find a solution to this problem where OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler doesn't take ClockSkew into account?

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented the OWIN with JWT oAuth 2.0. I faced the same issue after debugging I came to know that I was not setting my token issuer server expire time. by default its time is 20 mins only. please set AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan in OAuthServerOptions to your required time then this will work as a charm. Following is my code snippets hope this helps.

```
   public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var authuri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthURL"];
        var timeout = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeOut"]);
        var AllowInsecureHttp = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowInsecureHttp"]);

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            //Todo by Hasan : For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
            AllowInsecureHttp = AllowInsecureHttp,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout),
            Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(authuri)
        };

        // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

    }
```